# Drupal 6 Views Slideshow configuration

Tags: 6, views

I am trying to create a gallery like [this](http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/#ad-image-0).

It's been a while since I worked on a D6 site I am sure I have done this before on a few 2/3 year old websites.

**However, when I try configuring Views to generate my image gallery I don't get a slideshow style option**. I have attached an image to show the View configuration area to see what I mean.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the views slideshow module?

Comment: Yes. Along with cTool, Views and library

Comment: It's looking like you have Views 2 installed, so, make sure you have the right Views Slideshow module installed as there is one for Views 2 and another for Views 3.

Comment: @Jimajamma: Thank you. I found that to the issue earlier on after hours of looking. If you provide it as an answer I will be happy to mark it as correct to your credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking like you have Views 2 installed, so, make sure you have the right Views Slideshow module installed as there is one for Views 2 and another for Views 3 per the [Views Slideshow Module](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) page on drupal.org:

**Requirements**

- Views Slideshow 2.x requires Views 2.
- Views Slideshow 3.x requires Views 3.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a related issue when troubleshooting a Drupal 6 site that had been recently upgraded to a newer version of views and views slideshow. In the process, the existing slideshows had stopped working.

The problem was that Views Slideshow 2.x for Drupal 6 was changed from the earlier versions and the new version (6.x-2.4) requires you to *also* enable one of two sub-cmodules: Views Slideshow: SingleFrame or Views Slideshow: ThumbnailHover in order for it to work. Here's the relevant section of the Views Slideshow 6.x-2.4 readme file:

> ## Views Slideshow
>
> The Views Slideshow module is a Views Style Plugin that can be used to output
>   Views in a jQuery slideshow.
>
> There are currently 2 modes:
>
> SingleFrame
>
> In SingleFrame mode slideshows are output as single elements and controls can be
>   displayed as numbered links or thumbnails of individual fields.
>
> ThumbnailHover
>
> In ThumbnailHover mode slideshows are output as node teasers or full nodes. The
>   controls for advancing the slideshow are nodes too.
>
> Further details about each can be found within their respective directories.

I enabled SingleFrame and set it up in the view and the slideshow worked again.